Is it possible to download a instagram reel with audio, using instaloader?
I have been trying to download a instagram reel using instaloader, but it downloads the reel without audio every time. How can i download the unmuted reel or is it even possible.
I found this question posted by another guy, but the answer given here does not work. Or at least I don't know how to make it work.
Link of the question - Is there a way to download videos WITH sound with instaloader?
I am expecting that it should download the reel with sound.

I have a solution that works for me
Instaloader has a video_url property that gives a public CDN link to a the post, which I then download using requests library.
Here is the code
import instaloader
from instaloader import Post
import requests

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
post = Post.from_shortcode(L.context, <YOUR_REEL_ID>)
url = post.video_url
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                file.write(chunk)

